# SQL Server 2012 Query JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Construct a SQL query that will list the Street,City,State,ZipCode of all the addresses that DO NOT have a customer associated with them.

I am having issues understanding what this question is asking me to do. I can get as far as selecting Street, City, State, and ZipCode.

**I am using SQL Server 2012**

I have two tables:
    Customers (CustomerID (PK), CustomerName, CustomerAddressID(FK))
    Address(AddressID (PK),Street,City,State,ZipCode)

[image][image]

Comment: You have to find all the addresses in address table that are not present in the CustomerAddressID column of Customers. I am giving you a hint. Use a `left join`. See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: If you are learning SQL, the most natural way to approach this query is using `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Linking between Address and customer records exists in `CustomerAddressID` column in Customer table. Which means `Address.AddressID = Customer.CustomerAddressID`. You need to identify the records which doesnt satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's asking you to find all Addresses that don't have an associated Customer (so they may have an AddressId but no associated CustomerAddressId. To get that you could use the following:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Address a
LEFT JOIN Customer c 
    on c.CustomerAddressId = a.AddressId
WHERE c.CustomerId IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks mwan, I had a similar query but mine kept returning no results. I must have not been looking for the correct column.

Comment: No problems, if it solves the problem remember to mark it as answered. Next time remember to post the query you tried that didn't work, it makes it much easier to guide you in the right direction without explicitly posting the answer (which I did, but I realise it's not's the best way to learn).

Comment: Either click the "Code Sample" button (or press Ctrl + K) whilst in the answer editor or make sure each line is indented with 4 spaces.